# Sentiment Analysis in Spanish - Dictionary

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I'm interested in doing sentiment analysis in spanish. I've looked up in the web for an opinions dictionary and it seems imposible to find something similar as the existing ones in english. For example, http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html#lexicon

I'm new to the field and would be interested in some guidance, so I'm open to suggestions. How useful, for instance, would a standard Spanish dictionary be?

The object of study would be twitter posts related to politics.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a programming question in here?

Comment: Sentiment analysis, the next holy grial of programming and greed. can you imagine Facebook knowing exactly how you do feel?

`Sentiment analysis, also called opinion mining, is the field of study that analyzes people’s opinions, sentiments, evaluations, appraisals, attitudes, and emotions towards entities such as products, services, organizations, individuals, issues, events, topics, and their attributes.`

This question is related to AI. Remember me when the internet itself starts to do questions on networks like stackexchange.

Comment: Once [Open Data](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data?referrer=CDFFgLOWzATat7cFwtHzOQ2) goes into beta, this would be a good question there.

Comment: I've posted this question in Open Data: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/86/174

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if something like this already exists, but making one seems like it would definitely be a valuable thing to do for the community--though it might be a fair amount of work.

A standard Spanish dictionary probably won't really help you create a sentiment dictionary from scratch unless you're planning to manually assign sentiment values to a very large set of Spanish words. An English-to-Spanish dictionary might help you translate an English sentiment dictionary into a Spanish one, which, if nothing else, would probably be a good start, though it would be woefully lacking in its lack of common idioms, misspellings, and so forth.

One way that you *could* try using a standard Spanish dictionary would be to take the "starting point" you get from the above translation process and apply it to the *definitions* of Spanish words and phrases for which you haven't yet assigned a sentiment value; this would give you an easy way to extend your sentiment dictionary, though it might not be very accurate.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It has to be feed not only with a good dictionary, sources like magazines, blogs, images, sounds, discussions, video, etc. It requires be able to track individuals (how do you that even with data minning and AI? Undeniably information feed must interact with a real human interface, and is very far from [glass](https://www.google.com/glass/start/) (nice try google).

### Update:

I received an email from AlchemyAPI's marketing director (extract)

> *As a member of our API community, I thought you might be interested in
>   some recent press on AlchemyAPI's deep learning research. We are
>   constantly improving our natural language processing service and
>   moving forward with our goal to democratize artificial intelligence
>   technology.*
>
> *[MIT Technology Review](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/519726/a-google-glass-app-knows-what-youre-looking-at/) - A Google Glass App Knows What You're Looking At*
>
> *[GigaOM](http://gigaom.com/2013/09/19/alchemyapi-says-its-delivering-google-level-deep-learning-as-a-service/) - AlchemyAPI says it’s delivering Google-level deep learning as
>   a service*

They offer a [sentiment analysis API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/features/sentiment-analysis/).